# Avoid empty line after quote environment when last element in footnote

Tags: spacing, lists, footnotes, quoting

Is there any way to redefined the `quote` environment (or the `list` environment in general) so that it does not issue an empty new line. I need to have block quotes in footnotes and the extra empty line at the end looks really bad.

Minimal Example:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article} 
\title{Minimal Usecase}
\author{Canonical Chris}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\section{First section}
Your text goes here.\footnote{
  As my grandmother used to say:
  \begin{quote}
  Now it is time for all good people to come to the aid of their computer.
  Now it is time for all good people to come to the aid of their computer.
  Now it is time for all good people to come to the aid of their computer.  
  \end{quote}
}
And then more text goes here.\footnote{
   This footnote looks weird because the previous footnote adds that
   extra whitespace.
}
\end{document}
```

I would prefer a solution that does not involve adding new packages etc, since this is a small problem from a 500-page document.

Comment: footnote insert a finalstrut at the end, and this doesn't go well with the \par introduced by the quote. Insert some negative space: `\begin{quote} bbb\end{quote}\vspace{-10pt}`

Comment: Well, that is definitely easy to do and looks a lot better. Is there an easy way to compute how much the vspace should be, given the separation between footnotes? Is there some length that I can use?

Comment: footnote insert invisible text behind the quote. So the relevant length is the length behind a quote, something like `\vspace{\dimexpr-\topsep-\partopsep}`